# How to add padding to all child elements in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to add styling to child components of a React Native `View`. Since you cant use the `> *` selector in React Native's `StyleSheet.create` function how do you achieve this result?

Here is the code of a form I want to style:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.centered}>
    <Button mode="contained" onPress={onAddItem} style={styles.default}>
      Add Item
    </Button>
  </View>
  {showForm ? (
    <View style={styles.form}>
      <TextInput
        label="Title"
        returnKeyType="next"
        theme={{ colors: { primary: "blue", underlineColor: "transparent" } }}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        value={title.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTitle({ value: text, error: "" })}
        error={!!title.error}
        errorText={title.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <DropDownPicker
        label="Select Type"
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}
      />
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open2}
        value={value2}
        items={condition}
        setOpen={setOpen2}
        setValue={setValue2}
        setItems={setCondition}
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Quantity"
        returnKeyType="next"
        theme={{ colors: { primary: "blue", underlineColor: "transparent" } }}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        value={quantity.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setQuantity({ value: text, error: "" })}
        error={!!quantity.error}
        errorText={quantity.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
    </View>
  ) : null}
</View>;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly do you want to achieve by adding padding to every element? If it's how I understand, then you have no choice but to give style prop each and every component.

Comment: Create a view with padding and wrap each element with the created.

Comment: @İlker for styling purposes

Comment: From what I am able to understand, yes you need to add padding to all child components individually. @chackerian Can you upload the screenshots of your current UI and expected UI, so it will add more clarity to the question?